# Removing the "extract" character from a string

Tags: php

I have in my database lot of records with names. The names may have the character `\` in them, and I would like to remove it. I know that there is a function called `stripslashes` but it also removes this kind of slashes: `/` and I would like to keep them.

Therefore, I have tried the following code to do so:

```
str_replace('"\"',"",$row['name'])
```

It was a little bit tricky, since when I tried to chose to character to be removed, it extracted the single quotation mark, so I had to use 2 different quotation mark. Maybe I have done it wrong.

This isn't working for me for some reason, the strings are still keep being outputed with the `\` in them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and start using prepared statements with `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: @Rob If you could explain more about that, I would be glad.

Comment: Prepared statements in [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: `mysql_*` is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and prepared statements wont escape your quotes.

Comment: @Rob If I'm not being mistaken, the function `mysqli_real_escape_string()` also extractes characters as `'` and `"`, so why using it will be better than the normal one(instead of the normal one will be taken out at php 5.5)?

Comment: You dont need `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote()` with prepared statements.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "prepared statements" If you could send me some links which I could read what you are talking about, I would be greatful!

Comment: I already gave you 3 links.

Comment: @Rob My bad, haven't seen it. Thanks a lot! As I can see it, mysqli is a class, different from the normal mysql functions now. It's much different than what I'm being using. But I guess I can't be helped, and I will have to learn that since the normal methods are being removed soon enough. Thanks for letting me know! I will start learning mysqli as soon as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str_replace('\\', '', $row['name']);
```